# Backup EFS to S3 with Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-data-pipeline

I am writing a solution to backup an EFS file system to S3. When these backups happen, it should delete the previous backup. The way I am implementing this is through Terraform. In a Terraform, I am creating a data pipeline using a cloudformation stack. I am also creating 2 S3 buckets: one for logs for the data pipeline and one for backups of my EFS volumes. When executing my Terraform code, everything creates with no issues except for the Data Pipeline. I am getting a ROLLBACK_COMPLETE error. This is the exact error:

```
ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: ["The following resource(s) failed to create: [DataPipelineEFSBackup]. . Rollback requested by user." "Pipeline Definition failed to validate because of following Errors: [{ObjectId = 'ShellCommandActivityObj', errors = [Not a valid S3 Path. It must be of the form s3://bucket/key]}, {ObjectId = 'EC2ResourceObj', errors = [Not a valid S3 Path. It must be of the form s3://bucket/key]}] and Warnings: []"]
```

I cannot figure out why this is coming up. Below is also the code for the creation of my S3 Buckets, my cloudformation stack, and also the part of the Data Pipeline script that is producing this error. Any advice would be appreciated.

S3 Buckets

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "backup" {


bucket        = var.s3_backup
  force_destroy = true

  versioning {
    enabled = true
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    enabled = true
    prefix  = "efs"

    noncurrent_version_expiration {
      days = var.noncurrent_version_expiration_days
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "logs" {
  bucket        = var.s3_logs
  force_destroy = true
}
```

Data Pipeline

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "datapipeline" {


name          = "${var.name}-datapipeline-stack"
  template_body = file("scripts/templates/datapipeline.yml")

  parameters = {
    myInstanceType             = var.datapipeline_config["instance_type"]
    mySubnetId                 = aws_subnet.public.id
    mySecurityGroupId          = aws_security_group.datapipeline.id
    myS3LogBucket              = aws_s3_bucket.logs.id
    myS3BackupsBucket          = aws_s3_bucket.backup.id
    myEFSId                    = aws_efs_file_system.efs.id
    myEFSSource                = aws_efs_mount_target.efs.dns_name
    myTopicArn                 = aws_cloudformation_stack.sns.outputs["TopicArn"]
    myImageId                  = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux.id
    myDataPipelineResourceRole = aws_iam_instance_profile.resource_role.name
    myDataPipelineRole         = aws_iam_role.datapipeline_role.name
    myKeyPair                  = aws_key_pair.key_pair.key_name
    myPeriod                   = var.datapipeline_config["period"]
    myExecutionTimeout         = var.datapipeline_config["timeout"]
    Tag                        = var.name
    myRegion                   = var.region
  }
}
```

Data Pipeline Script

```
- Id: ShellCommandActivityObj
      Name: ShellCommandActivityObj
      Fields:
        - Key: type
          StringValue: ShellCommandActivity
        - Key: runsOn
          RefValue: EC2ResourceObj
        - Key: command
          StringValue: |
            source="$1"
            region="$2"
            destination="$3"
            sudo yum -y install nfs-utils
            [[ -d /backup ]] || sudo mkdir /backup
            if ! mount -l -t nfs4 | grep -qF $source; then
              sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1 -o rsize=1048576 -o wsize=1048576 -o timeo=600 -o retrans=2 -o hard "$source" /backup
            fi
            sudo aws s3 sync --delete --exact-timestamps /backup/ s3://$destination/
            backup_status="$?"
            if [ "backup_status" -eq "2"]; then
              backup_status="0"
            fi
            exit "$backup_status"
```